# Javascript get city name from google autocomplete or from lat and lng

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, geocoding

I find a way to get correct city name from google autocomplete or from lat and lng. Now I use this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {                 
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "locality") {$("#city").val(place.address_components[i].long_name);
         }
```

Now I use a type "locality" for city name, but sometimes for other addresses it may be "administrative_area_level_1", "administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_3" ..etc. 
How can I get CORRECT city name from address? 
Thanks for help.

For "Lenina, Minks, Belarus" I have such result:

```
 {
  "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "vulica Lienina",
           "short_name" : "vulica Lienina",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Minsk",
           "short_name" : "Minsk",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Belarus",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "vulica Lienina, Minsk, Belarus",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.9049197,
              "lng" : 27.5804421
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.8868641,
              "lng" : 27.553896
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.8958051,
           "lng" : 27.5659861
        },
        "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.9049197,
              "lng" : 27.5804421
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.8868641,
              "lng" : 27.553896
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJL_x0NsTP20YRE6LICTM5v2I",
     "types" : [ "route" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Lenina",
           "short_name" : "Lenina",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Slucki rajon",
           "short_name" : "Slucki rajon",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Minskaja voblasć",
           "short_name" : "Minskaja voblasć",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Belarus",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Lenina, Belarus",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.0604058,
              "lng" : 27.2418881
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.0405422,
              "lng" : 27.2215462
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.0546355,
           "lng" : 27.229549
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.0604058,
              "lng" : 27.2418881
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.0405422,
              "lng" : 27.2215462
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJNTp2Gl6t2UYRI1cE6L4oVh8",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  }
 ],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Result has two address_components...

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I extract the city name : (Working example with a geocoding results sample)

```js
let results = [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "vulica Lienina",
           "short_name" : "vulica Lienina",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Minsk",
           "short_name" : "Minsk",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Belarus",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "vulica Lienina, Minsk, Belarus",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.9049197,
              "lng" : 27.5804421
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.8868641,
              "lng" : 27.553896
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.8958051,
           "lng" : 27.5659861
        },
        "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.9049197,
              "lng" : 27.5804421
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.8868641,
              "lng" : 27.553896
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJL_x0NsTP20YRE6LICTM5v2I",
     "types" : [ "route" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Lenina",
           "short_name" : "Lenina",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Slucki rajon",
           "short_name" : "Slucki rajon",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Minskaja voblasć",
           "short_name" : "Minskaja voblasć",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Belarus",
           "short_name" : "BY",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Lenina, Belarus",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.0604058,
              "lng" : 27.2418881
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.0405422,
              "lng" : 27.2215462
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 53.0546355,
           "lng" : 27.229549
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 53.0604058,
              "lng" : 27.2418881
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 53.0405422,
              "lng" : 27.2215462
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJNTp2Gl6t2UYRI1cE6L4oVh8",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  }
 ]
   
let matches = results[0].address_components.filter(address_component =>
   ["locality", "colloquial_area"].some(word => ~address_component.types.indexOf(word)))

if (!matches || !matches.length) {
  console.log("Could not resolve city name.")
} else {
  console.log("Found city : ", matches[0].short_name) // Prints : Minsk
}
```

Comment: So you also use locality type for city? 
Yes, sometimes it works, but for example, for address "Lenina, Minsk, Belarus" it shows city name like "Lenina" but must show Minsk.

Comment: Could you add to your original question a sample of the results you can't exploit (like I did, a full results JSON) ?

Comment: I added json result to my post. And found that there are two address_components in the result . How can I use only firts address_components ?

Comment: I have just replaced my results with yours, and it outputs correctly "Minsk".

Comment: It is link to json: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lenina+Minsk+Belarus&sensor=true&language=en
` var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                let matches = place.address_components.filter(address_component =>
                        ["locality", "colloquial_area"].some(word => ~address_component.types.indexOf(word)));

                if (!matches  || !matches.length) {
                    return console.log("Could not resolve city name")
                }
                let foundCity = matches[0].short_name;` =locality from second address_components

Comment: Yes, I know, I saw your json, and I updated my answer with your json, and it works, as you can see. My code outputs : "Minsk". Now what's wrong?

Comment: I have error: result[0] is undefined 
I get result as: `var result = autocomplete.getPlace();`

Comment: Adapt my answer to your results structure, then. `result[0] is undefined` means it's not an array, very well, just use `results`, I don't know, just look at your structure.